# using a queue with threads in simple java program

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

i was just wondering if i could get some advice on some code

OK so i have a threaded class (very basic) basically calls this object whose code i will show just now...    this code is giving me a infinite wait() and i don't know why.

```
  public  void  play()
  {

     if(!queue.isEmpty()){
       synchronized(this)
       {
         if(queue.peek().ballCount <=AvailableGolfBalls)
         {
            //check if there all people in queue, if yes, give them preferance
             queue.poll().notify();
         }
     }
  }




hasBalls=false;

try
{
    while (!hasBalls)
    {
            if(AvailableGolfBalls >= count)
           {

                    AvailableGolfBalls -=count;
                    synchronized(this){
                      //the main code for thread
                     }

                    hasBalls=true;


            }
           else
            {
                //there isnt enough balls,wait
                queue.add(this);

                Thread.sleep(500);
                 System.out.println(ThreadID.get() +" -no balls availiable ");

                synchronized(this)
                {

                    this.wait();
                }

            }
    }


}
catch (InterruptedException exception)
{

}

AvailableGolfBalls +=count;
```

}

i simplified my code as much as i could, its a ridiculously simple program though, but i just started with multi threading a week ago and a lot of the concepts still confuse me.
what this program does is essentially is  every thread needs a certain amount of balls before it can run, if it doesn't have the required balls, stand in queue until its available.

Comment: I found this code hilarious. `if(!hasBalls)` aka `if(woman)`

Comment: one needs balls to code multithreading man, lol

Comment: `if(hasBalls) canMultiThread(); else cantMultiThread();`

Comment: im using a  private Queue<stuff> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<stuff>();//* for a queue

Comment: If you want a Queue with Threads I suggest using an ExecutorService as it is designed to do both, and provide manageability and task based control and results.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling notify while synchronizing on the correct object.

You are synchronizing on `this` and calling `notify` on an object stored in your queue. You must synchronize on objects stored in your queue to correctly call `notify` on them.

```
Object obj = null;
synchronized(this)
{
     if(queue.peek().ballCount <=AvailableGolfBalls)
     {
         //check if there all people in queue, if yes, give them preferance
         obj = queue.poll();
     }
}
if(obj!=null){
    synchronized(obj){
        obj.notify();
    }
}
```

This is what I *think* is wrong. Your code is very confusing because we don't know what type `this` is.

Comment: I think you should put obj in synchronized otherwise you will get a monitoring exception. Because this is not pointing to the same object as obj that will point to the object you polled from the queue.

Comment: the object is a object that each one of the thread calls, it is the class in which that method is saved.   is my logic right though? roughly?

Comment: Based on the code posted I can't comment whether your logic is correct as there's not enough information. Post more code *related to synchronization and threading* and I can help more.